# Getting Maximum update depth exceeded. Error even when I'm having a dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting data from local storage and rendering the whole component if the local storage has changed .. and I got this error and I don't know why.

it's a project about favorite movies and setting favorite items inside local storage and deleting from it

```
  let [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  let [tvs, setTvs] = useState([]);
  let [actors, setActors] = useState([]);
  let [fav,setFav]= useState([FavList])
```

```
  let getData =()=>{

  window.addEventListener('storage',()=>{
    let tvLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavTvs'));
    let moviesLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavMovies'));
    let peopleLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavActors'));
    
  if(tvLocal!=null&&tvLocal.length!=0){
    setTvs([...tvLocal])
  }else{setTvs([])}

  if(moviesLocal!=null&&moviesLocal.length!=0){
    setMovies([...moviesLocal])
  }else{setMovies([])}

  if(peopleLocal!=null&&peopleLocal.length!=0){
    setActors([...peopleLocal])
  }else{setActors([])}
  
  }
  )
```

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     getData()
   },[tvs,movies,actors])
```

i'm expecting an explanation or soluotion for this problem

Answer (score 0):

problem is listening localstorage. And in useEffect dependencies `[tvs,movies,actors]` To get storage values mostly right code in useEffect.

```
    useEffect (()=>{
let tvLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavTvs'));
        let moviesLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavMovies'));
        let peopleLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavActors'));
        
      if(tvLocal!=null&&tvLocal.length!=0){
        setTvs([...tvLocal])
      }else{setTvs([])}
    
      if(moviesLocal!=null&&moviesLocal.length!=0){
        setMovies([...moviesLocal])
      }else{setMovies([])}
    
      if(peopleLocal!=null&&peopleLocal.length!=0){
        setActors([...peopleLocal])
      }else{setActors([])}
      
      }
},[]);
```

Comment: i tried this and it works fine Thank you , but I'm trying to rerender the component if the storage changed and it also gives me this error 

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('storage',getData())
  },[tvs])  
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('storage',getData())
  },[actors])
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[movies]) 
I used this as aDidUpdate